# LIKE on one column and IN on another

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query where I have two columns to compare my data from but need a LIKE on one column. Something like this:

```
SELECT `name` , `country` 
FROM details
WHERE (`email`, `phone`)
IN (
("abc@abc.com",'%123'), ("def@def.com",'%456'), ("ghi@ghi.com",'%789') )
```

Please guide me on how I would write this query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one email can have multiple phone numbers but one search, you will need (or probably already have) a table with emails. In that you will need to add the search string and then do a locate instead of a like.

```
create table emaildetails (email char(20), phonesearch char(15))

insert into emaildetails values ("abc@abc.com", "302024")
insert into emaildetails values ("def@def.com", "024")
insert into emaildetails values ("ghi@ghi.com", "15")

select d.*,ed.* from details d, emaildetails ed
where d.email in ('abc@abc.com', 'ghi@ghi.com')
and d.email = ed.email
and locate(ed.phonesearch, d.phone)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would simplify the `where` clause to:

```
WHERE phone LIKE '%302024' AND
      email in ('abc@abc.com', 'def@def.com', 'ghi@ghi.com')
```

EDIT:

For your revised question, you can use a series of `AND` and `OR`:

```
WHERE (phone like '%123' and email = 'abc@abc.com) OR
      . . .
```

If the list is long, you might want to put the values into a table and use a `join` or `exists` clause.

Comment: Sorry, the phone numbers are different for each entry I will update my question. How would I write the query then?

Answer (score 0):

an IN statment as col `IN ('Foo', 'Foo%')` is equivalent to `(col = 'FOO' OR col = 'Foo%')` as you can see, that would not take into account the wildcard as in the `LIKE` clause, to achieve your requirements, you will need to divide your where clause as the following:

```
SELECT name, country 
  FROM details
 WHERE (phone LIKE '%123' OR phone LIKE '%456' OR phone LIKE '%789')
   AND email IN ('abc@abc.com', 'def@def.com', 'ghi@ghi.com')
```

Comment: mcha - I had this in this beginning, but realized that abc would go against 456 or 789 as well - not just 123. Thats not what is needed. I've posted another answer that takes care of this scenario.